# nil in UIPageControl view subview

Tags: ios, swift, null, uipagecontrol

I'm new in ios swift and want to change UIPageControl dots size via images.
I found same issue here ([UIPageControl custom class - found nil changing image to the dots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27941204/uipagecontrol-custom-class-found-nil-changing-image-to-the-dots))
but seems the answer is wrong, still in page control view subviews(UIImageView) is nil

As I don't have enough reputation have to ask here.

here how I'm adding image views to the scroll view

```
let imgOne = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0,scrollViewWidth, scrollViewHeight))
imgOne.image = UIImage(named: "1")
let imgTwo = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(scrollViewWidth, 0,scrollViewWidth, scrollViewHeight))
imgTwo.image = UIImage(named: "2")
let imgThree = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(scrollViewWidth*2, 0,scrollViewWidth, scrollViewHeight))
imgThree.image = UIImage(named: "3")
let imgFour = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(scrollViewWidth*3, 0,scrollViewWidth, scrollViewHeight))
imgFour.image = UIImage(named: "4")

self.scrollView.addSubview(imgOne)
self.scrollView.addSubview(imgTwo)
self.scrollView.addSubview(imgThree)
self.scrollView.addSubview(imgFour)
```

and below the answer to the problem

```
class PageControl: UIPageControl {
    var activeImage: UIImage!
    var inactiveImage: UIImage!
    override var currentPage: Int {
        willSet {
            self.updateDots()
        }
    }

    convenience init(activeImage: UIImage, inactiveImage: UIImage) {
        self.init()

        self.activeImage = activeImage
        self.inactiveImage = inactiveImage

        self.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        self.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    }

    func updateDots() {
        for var i = 0; i < count(subviews); i++ {
            var view: UIView = subviews[i] as! UIView
            if count(view.subviews) == 0 {
                self.addImageViewOnDotView(view, imageSize: activeImage.size)
            }
            var imageView: UIImageView = view.subviews.first as! UIImageView // nil
            imageView.image = self.currentPage == i ? activeImage : inactiveImage
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Private

    func addImageViewOnDotView(view: UIView, imageSize: CGSize) {
        var frame = view.frame
        frame.origin = CGPointZero
        frame.size = imageSize

        var imageView = UIImageView(frame: frame)
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.Center
        view.addSubview(imageView)
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... Are you saying the answer in that thread is wrong and proposing a correct solution (in which case you should post that as an answer in that question), or are you asking for help? If so, what exactly is your issue?

Comment: thanks for comment...

Comment: no this is not an answer, as I wrote I don't have enough reputation to write comment the existing one, that's why created new one.
My issue is I want to create custom page control to have bigger dots and different looks. My image has a white background and page control is not visible so I decided to change the page control

Comment: You want to create bigger dots with images right? So i think it is better to use UIButton in place of pager control so you can easily handle it separately and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Spending few days I solved it in the following way...
Don't know how is good the solution, feel free to to improve...
There was 2 problems

1:  in function updateDots, should look like this

```
func updateDots() {
    for var i = 0; i < subviews.count; i++ {
        var imageView: UIImageView? = nil
        let view: UIView = subviews[i]
        if (view.subviews.first is UIImageView) {
            if (subviews.count == 0) {
                addImageViewOnDotView(view, imageSize: activeImage.size)
            }
            imageView = (view.subviews.first as! UIImageView)
            imageView!.image = self.currentPage == i ? activeImage : inactiveImage
        }

        if (imageView == nil) {
            imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height));
            imageView!.image = self.currentPage == i ? activeImage : inactiveImage
            view.addSubview(imageView!)
        }
    }
}
```

2: When call this function, should be after (didSet) scroll not before (willSet)

```
override var currentPage: Int {
    didSet {
        self.updateDots()
    }
}
```